# When does Python Evaluate Object Properties?

Tags: python, properties

I'm trying to create a class attribute which updates dynamically. Apparently, **properties** are the way to go.
In the below code example I want to access my class attribute **c** during runtime. It shall update, when my attributes change. This does work as intended. However, I'd like **c** only being calculated, when I actually call it via **classobject.c** and not whenever I change any attribute, or when I first create my object.

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def c(self):
        c = fcn(self.a)
        return c

def fcn(a):
    n = int(1e7)
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        s += 1/i**2     # Grenzwert # pi^2/6
    return a + s
```

I thought thats how properties work anyway. But after creating a new class object, when I debug and watch obj variables (pycharm), I see the value of c, even though I have not yet called it. Is that only because pycharm calculates it, so that I can see it's value?

Comment: What code did you use to actually create an instance of `C`? Properties *do* work the way you assume: `fcn` is not called until you actually access the value of `c`.

Comment: "*Is that only because pycharm calculates it, so that I can see it's value?*"—Yes

Answer (score 0):

You might add `print` to your function and observe when it is called, consider following simple example

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    @property
    def b(self):
        b = func(self.a)
        return b

def func(x):
    print("func was called")
    return x*2

a = A(10)
print("a created")
b = a.b
```

gives output

```
a created
func was called
```